# Problem in Pytorch Installation on Python 3.8.5 with pip

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to install Pytorch on python 3.8.5 Windows 10 Machine with these commands:

```
pip install torch===1.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

and

```
pip install torch===1.6.0 torchvision===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

but I get this error always:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch===1.4.0 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch===1.7.0
```

any Advice?

Answer (score 1):

To install for `cuda` try out this one:

```
pip install torch==1.7.0+cu110 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

To install for `cpu` only, try out this one:

```
pip install torch==1.7.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

All the other option you can easily find [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/).

Comment: I tried different commands with pip but not working for me. but inside anaconda prompt working...

Comment: As for 5th October, 2023, MMCV building wheel issue solves by installing the solution you provided.

`pip install torch==1.7.0+cu110 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`